# Misbehaviour of Applescript: tell application "Terminal" to do script

Tags: osx-lion, applescript

On MacOS 10.7.5, the following Applescript

```
tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo foo"
```

opens a new Terminal window but foo is not printed. Using the command echo is nothing special, I can't get any command executed at all (I found the bug as I tried to have the command cd executed). I found a workaround:

```
tell application "Terminal" 
  do script
  do script "echo foo" in window 1
end tell
```

Am I missing something? Or is it the expected behaviour?

Comment: Nit: `cd` is a special shell command, not a program (and vice-versa) ..

Comment: Also, I can run your first command in the AppleScript Editor and it "works as expected" (10.7.5 as well).

Comment: Any reason you're using terminal over `do shell script`?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use:

```
do shell script "echo foo"
```

But, if you want the response of the shell script, you can use:

```
set shellresponse to do shell script "echo foo"
```